# wkhtmltopdf randomly failes by converting same file

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf (via a PHP-wrapper) to convert some html files to pdf.
All in all it's working great, but in 20% it just crashes without any rather information. So without changing the input file it sometimes works fine and sometimes it doesn't.

This is the output i get by failing:

```
Could not create PDF:
Could not run command '/www/htdocs/example/projekte/example/test/wkhtmltopdf-amd64' --ignore-load-errors "http://www.example.de/projekte/example/test/ebene/example/lieferschein-geschirr-material/lieferschein-geschirr-material.php?PHPSESSID=250cd07e432cd69eba2aa51054577d63&testmodus=1" /tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_CkYxRt:
Loading pages (1/5) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [============> ] 21% [===============> ] 25% [============================================================] 100% Resolving links (2/5) [============================================================] Page 1 of 1 Counting pages (3/5) [============================================================] Page 1 of 1 Printing pages (5/5) [> ] Preparing [=======> ] Page 1 of 8 [===============> ] Page 2 of 8 [======================> ] Page 3 of 8 [==============================> ] Page 4 of 8 [=====================================> ] Page 5 of 8 [=============================================> ] Page 6 of 8 [====================================================> ] Page 7 of 8 [============================================================] Page 8 of 8 Done
```

I don't have any explanation for that. Does anyone maybe know this problem and can help?

Comment: Do you ever do the conversions concurrently, two or more conversions at a time? Our wkhtmltopdf has had some threading issues and I don't think they have gone away. As suggested in the comments for https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=511 it might help if you implement a conversion queue of sorts. If this happens when coverting one by one I'm a bit clueless.

Comment: There are no simultaneous conversions running. It's even happening by converting just one nearly blank page with a single access. But anyway thanks for the hint!

I do still not know why this is happening, but it's a bug of the PHP-Wrapper I used (http://mikehaertl.github.com/phpwkhtmltopdf/). I switched to an alternative version that is given on http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp and it is working right know.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are putting wrong o/p file. use it as  `/tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_CkYxRt.pdf` rather than  `/tmp/tmp_WkHtmlToPdf_CkYxRt` i.e you have some issue with the calling of class functions.